# Получить все стили конкретного окна WinApi

Tags: c, winapi

Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить информацию о стилях применённых к окну ?
Если, я правильно понимаю, то это цели служит функция GetWindowLongPtr, она как раз может извлекать и возвращать стили/расширенные стили окна.

То есть возвращаемое значение это будет число типа LONG - это число и будет является комбинацией всех стилей приименных к окну.
Но, я не могу понять, как мне из этого числа вычленить значениях именно всех этих стилей ?
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Встречный вопрос, зачем вам это могло понадобиться? Почему вам не хватает числа которое вы получаете?

Comment: – こきん , число - это совокупность стилей. А мне нужно узнать есть ли конкретный стиль на окне или нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вначале получаете этот стиль

```
DWORD styles = GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd,GWL_STYLE);
```

а потом последовательно проверяете все варианты. Где то так

```
if (styles & WS_CAPTION) {
    puts("WS_CAPTION was set");
} else {
    puts("Style wasn't set");
}
```

Список стилей можно найти здесь https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles

Некоторые стили там комбинированные, например WS_POPUPWINDOW = (WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER | WS_SYSMENU). С ними нужно быть аккуратным. Тут все зависит от того, что именно Вы хотите показать. Возможно тут где то так

```
if (styles & WS_POPUPWINDOW ) {
    puts("WS_POPUPWINDOW");
} else {
   // проверяем по отдельности WS_POPUP, WS_BORDER, WS_SYSMENU
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, перестаньте редактировать мой ответ. ОСТАНОВИТЕСЬ!

Comment: Пожалуйста пишите ответ на том языке, который стоит в вопросе.

Comment: Вы отредактировали немного больше.

Comment: Согласен, стиль я подправил для понятности кода, т.е. не было ясно что и где. А за ответ + =)

Comment: я запостил ответ, а потом вспомнил, что там си. Пошел редактировать, но я этого не могу сделать - оно мне выкидывает, что ответ изменен.